# NodeJs project build errors not printing in jenkins console

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jenkins, console.log

In Jenkins console output, I'm able to see the NodeJs(AngularCLI logs etc) running but not able to get the error log of Nodejs project in the console output. Which we can see in the local build. It exit after the following line and not display the error logs.  After

```
94% asset optimization                       fs.js:885
return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
```

the error logs which we get after

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: try : ng build --prod | tee npm.log. it will create a logfile with the stdout of the npm process . its not an answer, just a workaround

Answer (score 0):

So was using the below line

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --env=dev --output-path=dist/dev
```

which was checking the 3rdpartylicense, changed it to

`node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --env=dev --output-path=dist/dev --no-extract-licenses`

Note: added  --no-extract-licenses

The logs started showing up